# Failed to Log in to Ubuntu Software Centre to Review Items

Tags: software-center, reviews

I successfully Signed-Up to Ubuntu Software Center once, to Review an Item and I successfully Reviewed it. But later when I wanted to review an Item again and clicked on "Write Your Own Review" it is saying "Failed to Log in". I searched every where in Software Center to find a place to get Logged in and Couldn't find it. My question is Where can I Logged in ?. I'm Using Ubuntu 14.04LTS version.
Also I couldn't find Ubuntu Software Center in the "Passwords and Keys" window.

Comment: Where can I find the Log in information for Software Center in my Computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in by going to the toolbar at the top of the Ubuntu Software Center and clicking `File` > `Reinstall Previous Purchases` > and a a new Dialogue should open up to sign in.

Comment: Only a empty window(Software Center Heading is there ) with a title Previous Purchases. Nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

Try Uninstalling and re-installing the software center.

First open terminal `CTRL + ALT + T`

and copy and paste the following

```
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center
```

If this dont work I would recommend reporting a bug

Comment: I tried it, But Same problem Continues.